# Writing an app with Perl and Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, perl

I am working on a project that is mostly Ruby on Rails. However, I need to generate and parse Excel files in this project (I know, I know...), so I've been using Perl's Spreadsheet::WriteExcel and Spreadsheet::ParseExcel which work well. However, what is the best way to combine this use of Perl with the larger Ruby on Rails app? Is calling the Perl script with backticks the kosher way to go about this? It feels a little hacky to me, but if that is the only (or best) way, then that's what I'll do. I wanted to reach out and see if anyone else has some suggestions or advise.

Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's also the [speadsheet gem](http://rubygems.org/gems/spreadsheet), although I've never used it for writing.

I don't think there's anything intrinsically wrong with using backticks or `%x()`, although I might instead expose the Perl stuff as a service to make it a bit more general purpose. Likely overkill, though.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the gem! I'll take a look. I think the service route might be the best way to go for this particular project though, even if it might be overkill. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

You might look into making a simple RESTful application using a Perl webapp framework, like [Mojolicious](http://mojolicio.us). Your RoR app could simply make calls to the Perl app and get some JSON back.

Here is a very simple app, of course your `get_data` would do something, I just have it return a simple hash. Once you have installed Mojolicious you can run it with one of its built-in servers, for example: `morbo myapp.pl` (assuming the following is saved as `myapp.pl` of course)

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use Mojolicious::Lite;

get '/:query' => sub {
  my $self = shift;
  my $query = $self->param( 'query' );
  my $data = get_data( $query );
  $self->render( json => $data );
};

app->start;

sub get_data {
  my $query = shift;
  # do something here, like parse some excel file
  # I will just make some silly data
  my $data = { $query => $query };
  return $data;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how much third-party stuff it supports, but there is the [ruby-perl](https://github.com/zephirworks/ruby-perl) project: embedded Perl within Ruby.